# Why is username required when I set email as username in Custom user definition

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am. trying to create Django backend for my application. For authentication I am using django authentication where I needed to create `CustomUser` model for my specific use case. After trying to insert new user I am encountering this error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_customuser_username_key" DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.`

I will add full traceback below.

I have also included this line in **settings.py** `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"`

This is my function that I use for creating new user:

```py
from .models import CustomUser
from .dto import UserRegistrationDto, JWTDto

def create_user_in_database(data: UserRegistrationDto) -> JWTDto:

        user = CustomUser.objects.create(first_name=data.first_name, last_name=data.last_name,birthdate=data.birthdate, email=data.email)
        user.set_password(data.password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

My CustomUser model definition:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    key = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=1,null=False)
    tier = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=False)
    used_capacity = models.FloatField(default=0.0,null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["birthdate","first_name","last_name"]
```

My DTO class:

```py
class UserRegistrationDto(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ["first_name","last_name","birthdate","email","password"]
```

Full traceback:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_customuser_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_customuser_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ninja/operation.py", line 107, in run
    result = self.view_func(request, **values)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oliverbielik/Documents/cloud_project/backend/cloud_hub_backend/cloud_hub_backend/apps/users/views.py", line 13, in register_user
    create_user = UserQueries.create_user_in_database(data)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/oliverbielik/Documents/cloud_project/backend/cloud_hub_backend/cloud_hub_backend/apps/users/queries.py", line 12, in create_user_in_database
    user = CustomUser.objects.create(first_name=data.first_name, last_name=data.last_name,birthdate=data.birthdate, email=data.email)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 78, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "//Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/backend-y-HyWMBZ-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_customuser_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.
```

I am not sure where the problem might be because I defined CustomUser exactly like [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) is saying.

Comment: Have you checked into the table in your database? It seems like you already have a user with the requested email.

Comment: I can create one user but if I try to create other new user with different data i get this error. Also my first usere wont store password hash for some reason. And I am using different data for new user double checked that. 

The problem is that it's setting field `username` to empty string with First and every other user even though i explicitly defined that  `USERNAME_FIELD = "email"` is email not username.